# How to diagnose an error with W3WP.exe in a WCF service hosted by IIS7

Tags: .net, wcf, iis-7

I've a .net WCF service hosted on an application server with windows 2008/IIS 7.0.
I see following error message in the event log:

Faulting application w3wp.exe, version 7.0.6001.18000, time stamp 0x47919413, faulting module ntdll.dll, version 6.0.6001.18000, timestamp 0x4791a7a6, exception code 0xc00000374, fault offset 0x000b015d, process id 0x2a70, application start time 0x01ca37385743ae83

What does it mean and how do i resolve the issue?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To be clear, this is an error occurring in the IIS worker process (w3wp.exe).  The error code indicates heap corruption, as explained in this [IIS forum post](http://forums.iis.net/t/1150912.aspx).  To solve these problems often requires lots of complicated debugging and memory dumps that can be analyzed.

Without knowing anything more about the nature of your WCF service, I can't really give you any more guidance.